# How do I increase WiFi signal strength and speed on laptop?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, connection

I have 2 laptops both have the same wifi device intel Centrino Wireless-N 2230 ___ I have a 100Mb internet connection.

Dell Vostro 5460 gets low signals and speed of around one 1mb only

dell Inspiron 5520 gets relatively higher signals and speed of around 20+ Mb

the driver is updated and of the same version on both laptops and both laptops are placed at one place, the same distance from wifi router.

Comment: Check the wireless mode of Vostro 5460 under device manager->network adapter. select  the adapter, double click, select advanced. Set it to a higher mode if it is not

Comment: Everything is the same in the advanced tab for both laptops, I tried to change in Vostro but no benefit. __ windows version is also same for both. Inspiron is windows 10 pro and Vostro is windows 10 home

Answer (score 0):

Try and just use one and see what happens. It could also be that there is interference with the signal. It could also be that there are software limitations, or the laptop cannot go higher than that.

Try to also use ethernet, and see what happens.

Comment: I tried but no benefit, on an ethernet near the router it works perfectly but I don't have an ethernet cable in my room I need wifi.---  in fact, if I make a mobile hotspot in Inspiron and use it in Vostro then Vstro gives the same internet speed as Inspiron. But I can not use both laptops all time just for a mobile hotspot.

Comment: I have a USB wifi antenna, I tried it both in Inspiron and Vostro. Vostro again slow.... but Vostro is fast on ethernet, or near the router or using mobile hotspot of Inspiron... I think the Processor or motherboard is not giving enough power to the wifi capability of Vostro.